# MATLAB string to number error

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a dozens of arrays with different array names and I would like to do some mathematical calculations in to for loop array by array. I srucked in calling these array into for loop. Is there anybody can help me with this problem? text1 array contains array names. My "s" struct has all these arrays with the same name content of text1 array.

```
text1=['s.CustomerArray.DistanceDriven','s.CustomerArray.TimeDriven'];

for i=1:3
    parameter=str2num(text1(i));
    k=size(parameter,2);
    a=100;
    y=zeros(a,k);

end
```

After this part my some other calculations should start using "parameter"

Regards,

Eren

Comment: What are you hoping will go into `parameter`?? Also `text1(1)` will give you `'s'`, `text1(2)` will give you `'.'` etc... which I'm sure is not what you want at all. I think maybe you should expand your explanation to include an example

Comment: So what is the problem? Do you get en error and if so which one?

Comment: 's.CustomerArray.DistanceDriven' and 's.CustomerArray.TimeDriven' are coming as a text with xlsread function. In my workspace these arrays has an numbers which I want to use later. My purpose is convert these string array to number array. str2num doesnt work in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing several things wrong, here are some pointers.

Rather than listing them manually, consider looping over the `fieldnames` which can be obtained automatically.

If you are looping over strings, make sure to use a `cell array` with , rather than a `matrix`.

If you have a constant, declare it outside the loop, rather than inside the loop. This won't break the code but just makes for obsolete evaluations.

If you want to store results obtained inside a loop, make sure to add an index to the variable that you loop over.

---

That being said, here is a guess at what you are trying to do:

```
f = fieldnames(s.CustomerArray);
y = cell(numel(f),1);
parameter = NaN(numel(f),1);
for t = 1:numel(f)
    parameter(t) = s.CustomerArray.(f{t});
    y{t} = zeros(100,numel(f{t}));
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your advices. I am looping over strings but my point is reach numeric values of this string name arrays inside the workspace.

Comment: @user3145941 Assuming the array with that name exists, this should be what you now get in `parameter`. Try `a.b=1;s='b';a.(s)` to understand how to access values of named structs.